# How to set display ratio between widgets in Qt layout?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

In a tab page I do have one tree view widget and one tab widget inside the vertical layout, I want to set 60% of screen space to tree view and 40% to tab widget, always. How can I do this in Qt Designer ?

Platform: Qt Creator 2.4.1 / Win 7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you click the parent widget and scroll down its properties, you will find the properties of its layout at the very bottom.

You can set the `layoutRowStretch` and `layoutColumnStretch` properties there.
In case of a vertical layout, you could for example set "60,40" (or "6,4" or "3,2") as value for the `layoutRowStretch` property.

This will mean the factor of the first row to the second row will be 60:40 = 3:2